# How to Force For Office 365 Login With SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, security, networking

In my previous company whenever I connected to an Azure SQL Server via SQL Server Management Studio it was asking me to enter my Office 365 credentials to access the server.

However, when we were deploying the applications on Azure Web Applications we were using created SQL Server users that have strong passwords. They were okay without an Office 365 login. The purpose of this was security from people who know SQL Server usernames and passwords or a leak.

How can I enable this on Azure SQL Server? Basically, If your IP address is not an Azure IP address doesn't matter if you put the right username or password. You have to verify via the Office 365 login prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Azure AD authentication for the Azure SQL database to secure it by following the procedure below:

Go to Azure SQL Server, navigate to Microsoft Enter ID, and click Set Admin. Select the AD user you want to add as admin, and click Save, as shown below:

[image]

After that, when connecting to the Azure SQL Database using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), Office 365, or other tools, you can choose "Active Directory - MFA" as the authentication method and provide your Azure AD credentials. This will be more secure compared to using an Azure SQL Server username and password.

Comment: Thanks! Will this integrate the existing Azure or IIS applications which have the mixed mode auth modal?

Comment: Azure SQL server is having mixed mode of authentication

Comment: I've followed the steps on the image. I took one of the SQL Server usernames and passwords and tried from another remote machine which is not in the network or signed in to Office 365. The Azure SQL Server accepted credentials and did not ask any Office 365 login. The problem still exists.

Comment: Use Active directory -MFA authentication method instead of sql server user name and password.

Comment: There are applications that we can not touch due we do not know the impact. The aim here is secure the login for developers who are not using Azure IP addresses.

Comment: This will not impact on any application, it is just adding another authentication mode to secure the login.